# RecyclerView con Firebase en Fragment Android

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-fragment, recyclerview

Estoy haciendo una aplicación donde tengo almacenado información en una base de datos en Firebase, quiero que la información se muestre en un Fragment pero no muestra absolutamente nada, me podrían ayudar diciéndome cual es mi error.

Layout del Fragment

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dialog_margin"
android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dialog_margin" >

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerViewPlanes"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

</androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>
```

Layout de lo que va contener el recyclerview

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnPlanesS"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/Acep"/>
```

La clase para obtener la información de Firebase

```
public class Planes {

private String texto;

public Planes(){

}

public Planes(String texto){
    this.texto = texto;
}

public String getTexto() {
    return texto;
}

public void setTexto(String texto) {
    this.texto = texto;
} 
}
```

Y finalmente el FragmentActivity

```
public class SendFragment extends Fragment {

private RecyclerView recyclerViewPlanes;

private DatabaseReference mDatabase;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private String currentUserID;

public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                         ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_send, container, false);

    recyclerViewPlanes = root.findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewPlanes);
    recyclerViewPlanes.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    currentUserID = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");

    return root;
}

@Override
public void onStart() {

    super.onStart();

    FirebaseRecyclerOptions options =
            new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Planes>()
            .setQuery(mDatabase.child(currentUserID).child("Nombre"), Planes.class)
            .build();

    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Planes, PlanesViewHolder> adapter
            = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Planes, PlanesViewHolder>(options) {
        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final PlanesViewHolder planesViewHolder, int i, @NonNull Planes planes) {

            String nPlan = getRef(i).getKey();
            mDatabase.child(nPlan).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    if(dataSnapshot.exists()){

                        //String mPlan = dataSnapshot.getChildren().toString();
                        String mPlan = dataSnapshot.getValue().toString();

                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Nombre: " + mPlan, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        planesViewHolder.mButton.setText(mPlan);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public PlanesViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.planes_view, parent, false);

            PlanesViewHolder viewHolder = new PlanesViewHolder(view);

            return viewHolder;
        }
    };

    recyclerViewPlanes.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.startListening();
}

public static class PlanesViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    Button mButton;

    public PlanesViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        mButton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnPlanesS);
    }
}
}
```

Base de datos en Firebase

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al momento que inicio la aplicación y voy al fragment que seleccione desde un Navigation Drawer, debería mostrar un botón con un texto obtenido de la base de datos de firebase, pero no se muestra nada. Me gustaría que mostrará los hijos dentro de Plan

A que se deberá?

Comment: Podrias poner una foto de tu base de datos ?

Comment: Ya agregue como esta estructurada la base de datos.